# Adding to XAML WPF from ViewModel (MVVM)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

first attempt at MVVM and WPF (steep learning curve).
In my ViewModel I want to run the following code to add a "layoutDocument" which is an AvalonDock layout into my Mainform UI.

ViewModel class:

```
LayoutDocument layoutDocument = new LayoutDocument { Title = "Plan Layout" };

Window mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<Window>().Where(x => x.Name == "MainWindow").FirstOrDefault();
if (mainWindow != null)
{
    mainWindow.mainPanel.Children.Add(layoutDocument);
}
```

The above code gives me the following error:

"'Window' does not contain definition for 'mainPanel' and no extension method for 'mainPanel'".

Note in my XAML below that "LayoutDocumentPane" does contain a name "mainPanel".

I have tried adding the above code directly into my MainForm View Class (excluding the Application.Current.Windows.OfType and If statement bit) and just including the:
    mainPanel.Children.Add(layoutDocument);
And it works fine (a new layout is created in my MainForm when I click the button).

However, as I want to stickto MVVM this is not a suitable solution.

How can I add "layoutDocument" to MainWindow from ViewModel? Thanks in advance.

An extract of my XAML looks like this:

```
<Window x:Class="LiveExplorer.MainWindow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LiveExplorer"
             xmlns:xctk="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit"
             xmlns:xcad="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/avalondock"
             xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:WpfApp1.ViewModel">

<Grid> etc etc etc here---

                <xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup>
                    <xcad:LayoutDocumentPane x:Name="mainPanel">
                        <xcad:LayoutDocument ContentId="document1" Title="Document 1" >
                            <Button Content="Document 1 Content" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                    Command="{Binding NewPlanCommand, Source={StaticResource viewModel}}" 
                                    />
                        </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                        <xcad:LayoutDocument ContentId="document2" Title="Document 2">
                            <TextBox Text="Document 2 Content" AcceptsReturn="True"/>
                        </xcad:LayoutDocument>
                    </xcad:LayoutDocumentPane>
                </xcad:LayoutDocumentPaneGroup >
```

### EDIT:

Whilst the accepted answer does not answer the question in terms of MMVM, it does correct the coding error.

Comment: Adding child controls to the UI components from the View models is not the MVVM pattern. View model shouldn't be aware of the view's components. You should have a data binding in your xaml to either a collection, if you want to add multiple or a property of your view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not related to MVVM but to be able access the `mainPanel` you need to cast the returned `Window` to a `MainWindow`:

```
MainWindow mainWindow = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
if (mainWindow != null)
{
    mainWindow.mainPanel.Children.Add(layoutDocument);
}
```

A view model shouldn't access any window directly though. This breaks the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 3):

What you've tried to implement does not follow the MVVM pattern. You need to take care of 3 things to get started:

- ViewModels
- Initialize the ViewModel binded to the window
- Binding ViewModel to the UI in XAML

**ViewModels:**

Create a viewmodel that will be binded to your MainWindow and create an observable collection inside that MainWindowViewModel that contains a list of object that will contain data that can be used in the UI:

```
public ObservableCollection<LayoutDocumentViewModel> LayoutDocument {get;set;}
```

Make sure that both the MainWindowViewModel and the LayoutDocumentViewModel inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged([Implement Property Change Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification)) or if you use MVVMLight (or similar) from ViewModelBase.

The LayoutDocumentViewModel is just a ViewModel that will be used to store information about your layout document and that can be binded to the UI.

```
public LayoutDocumentViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] 
        string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
      get { return _name; }
      set
      {
          _name = value;
          // Call OnPropertyChanged whenever the property is updated
          OnPropertyChanged("Name");
      }
    }

}
```

I would strongly recommend that you use MVVMLight (or similar) or put the INotifyPropertyChange code into a base class i.e. ViewModelBase for example.

For simplicity sake in this example, I'm initializing the observable collection and creating a couple of document layouts objects directly in the MainWindowViewModel but you'll need to research this further and find out where it is appropriate for you to initialize and/or create these.

public MainPageViewModel()
{
   DocumentLayouts = new ObservableCollection();
   DocumentLayouts.Add(new DocumentLayout {Name="Layout1"});
   DocumentLayouts.Add(new DocumentLayout {Name="Layout2"});
}

The above takes care of creating your MainWindowViewModel and layout documents.

**Initializing MainViewModel** (and binded to the MainWindow.xaml). Note this is a quick and dirty way to get you started and you should really look into IoC containers.

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Finally, bind your ViewModel & UI

**XAML:**

```
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding LayoutDocuments}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

Note: Just replace the Label by your LayoutDocument control and bind it to the relevant element properties you have declared in LayoutDocumentViewModel.

Hope this helps get you started.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent answer. Everything you say makes sense and is no doubt the correct way. If I'm honest, despite going through several examples, data binding and INotifyChange etc hasn't clicked for me yet, so for now I'm going to use 'mm8' answer just so I can move forwards. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome! It does take a little time to get use to and to be honest, there are still plenty of scenarios where I still struggle today but this is where SO comes in :) - Best of luck!